# Google Cloud Compute Engine CentOS 7 image missing /usr/share/google directory

Tags: centos7, google-compute-engine

I have installed CentOS in the distant past and /usr/share/google directory existed.  But the current image (x86_64 built on 2016-06-29) offered does not include this directory.  This is also true of the CentOS 6 image.  I am specifically looking for safe_format_and_mount, and I've searched the system and it is not found anywhere.  Does anyone know why it is missing, and more importantly, how to get it installed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because errors and omissions in third party images should be addressed to those parties so they can correct the problem.

Comment: @Iain You can't be serious.  I love StackExchange, but I can't stand the crowd that hangs around trying to block the flow of information from someone who has it to someone who doesn't over something as stupid as this blah blah blah crap you're giving me.  Clearly, with a legitimate answer given, some people would disagree that the question is off topic.  Fortunately for me and anyone who now googles for centos 7 missing /usr/share/google, you didn't get to close my question before the answer was posted.  Thank you for the answer, Faizan.

Comment: I agree Joe!  StackExchange needs to find some other way of keeping content quality high rather than closing questions.  If a solution is found that means something to someone at least.  I was very happy to find this question and answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'safe_format_and_mount' tool is deprecated and is not included in new VM images. To format and mount disks, you can use mkfs.ext4 and mount tool which comes preinstalled with Linux images. The steps are documented on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting).

Comment: You can refer to [this github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/saltbase/salt/helpers/safe_format_and_mount) which has safe_format_and_mount script for Kubernetes hypekube image.

Comment: Thanks Faizan.  Is it safe to use the script from the github repo?  Why was safe_format_and_mount deprecated?  I couldn't see any mention of deprecation in Google Cloud docs when I search (but I am sure it was probably mentioned in update).  Seems strange to remove something that was useful (at least for me).